# Calculating 24 from 4 numbers (math Poker game)

Tags: python, algorithm, game, combinatorics

This is a game of math in Poker. Two people each have a pile of cards. They then each place 2 cards on the table at the same time. Every card is treated as a number. The players need to find a way to calculate 24 from the numbers. For example, you are given 3 5 4 8, and you can get 24 by (3+8-5) * 4, or 8*4-5-3. This code tries to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me to improve it?

**`comp()`**

```
def comp( nums,i,j,exps,op):
    nums0=[];
    for x in range(0,len(nums)):
        if not (x==i or x==j):
            nums0.append(nums[x])

    if(op=='+'):
        tmp = nums[i]+nums[j];
    elif(op=='*'):
        tmp = nums[i]*nums[j];
    elif(op=='-'):
        tmp = nums[i]-nums[j];
    elif(op=='/'):
        if(nums[j]<0.0001 and nums[j]>-0.0001 ):
            tmp=100000;
        else:
            tmp = nums[i]*1.0/nums[j];
    elif(op=='^'):
        return comp(nums,j,i,exps,'-');
    elif(op=='%'):
        return comp(nums,j,i,exps,'/');

    exps.append(str((nums[i],op,nums[j])));
    nums0.append(tmp);
    return nums0
```

**`cal()`**

```
def cal(nums, exps):
    if(len(nums)==1):
        return (nums[0]>23.9999 and nums[0]<24.0001);
    pairs = {};
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
            tmp_key= str((min(nums[i],nums[j]),max(nums[i],nums[j])));
            #print tmp_key
            if(pairs.has_key(tmp_key)):
                continue;
            #print 'put '+tmp_key
            pairs[tmp_key]=''
            for op in ('+','-','*','/','^','%'):
                nums0 = comp(nums,i,j,exps,op)
                if(cal(nums0,exps)):
                    print str(exps);
                exps.pop();
```

---

```
cal([3,9,10,7],[]);

cal([5,5,5,1],[]);

cal([10,9,4,1],[]);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why this has been downvoted. Can someone explain?

Comment: @GarethRees The question is now good, but Rev 1 of the question was a code dump with no explanation of purpose.

Comment: Another nice shortcut you can use: `-0.0001 < nums[j] < 0.0001`

Comment: solutions can be grouped by two categories: // ($a, $b) and ($c, $d)
or // ((($a, $b), $c), $d) https://helloacm.com/24/

Comment: use `if tmp_key in pairs` in python3

Answer (score 6):

A few pieces of feedback:

- Semi-colons in Python aren't necessary, unless you're trying to issue two commands on one line like `a=5;b=6`.  I couldn't find a pep style guide that specifically bans them, but most Python code doesn't use them, as they are unnecessary.
- You set `temp_key` to a `str`, but that is unnecessary.  I'm assuming you added that because you probably had it as a list before and got a "unhashable" error when trying to use a list as a dictionary key.  This is a perfect spot to use a tuple, and your code will work if you just remove the `str` (leaving the `()`), because tuples are hashable and immutable.
- Instead of relying on floating point accuracy, which isn't a problem given the magnitude of your examples, an alternative would be to use the fractions class and all your calculations would be exact.
- Instead of recursively calling the comp function for your inverse negative and inverse divide, it'd probably be much simpler to just write `tmp = nums[j]-nums[i]`.  I'd suggest it for the inverse divides too.

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is formatting. Here's your code reformatted to look nice.

```
def comp(nums, i, j, exps, op):
    nums0 = []
    for x in range(0, len(nums)):
        if not (x == i or x == j):
            nums0.append(nums[x])

    if op == '+':
        tmp = nums[i] + nums[j]
    elif op == '*':
        tmp = nums[i] * nums[j]
    elif op == '-':
        tmp = nums[i] - nums[j]
    elif op == '/':
        if nums[j] < 0.0001 and nums[j] > -0.0001:
            tmp = 100000
        else:
            tmp = nums[i] * 1.0 / nums[j]
    elif op == '^':
        return comp(nums, j, i, exps, '-')
    elif op == '%':
        return comp(nums, j, i, exps, '/')

    exps.append(str((nums[i], op, nums[j])))
    nums0.append(tmp)
    return nums0

def cal(nums, exps):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums[0] > 23.9999 and nums[0] < 24.0001;
    pairs = {}
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            tmp_key = str((min(nums[i], nums[j]), max(nums[i], nums[j])))
            # print tmp_key
            if pairs.has_key(tmp_key):
                continue
            # print 'put ' + tmp_key
            pairs[tmp_key] = ''
            for op in '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '%':
                nums0 = comp(nums, i, j, exps, op)
                if cal(nums0, exps):
                    print(str(exps))
                exps.pop()
```

I removed the semicolons, added proper spacing and removed useless parentheses. I also put brackets on the `print` so it works on Python 3, but that's optional.

Further, there are a lot of trivial non-formatting touch-ups:

- `has_key` is long deprecated; use the `in` operator.
- `range(0, x)` is just `range(x)`.
- `for i in range(len(vals))` is better as `for i, _ in enumerate(vals)`
- List comprehensions are great.
- `not (x == i or x == j)` just looks cleaner as `x != i and x != j`
- `x < upper_bound and x > lower_bound` is just `lower_bound < x < upper_bound`.
- `x * 1.0 / y` is just `x / float(y)`, which is just `x / y` with `from __future__ import division`
- `itertools.combinations` is your friend
- `(min(x, y), max(x, y))` is `tuple(sorted((x, y)))`
- Dead comments are rotting comments. Remove them.
- `pairs` is being used as a `set`, so use a `set`.
- Move values down to where they're used; don't leave them hanging... especially if you might just discard them first.
- Recursion in `comp` seems to be doing more harm than good. Moving your strange division to another function deals with this better.
- Throw an error for unknown operators
- Get rid of `tmp` in `comp` by moving the operation to another function
- Your naming is poor. Try to write meaningful names.
- `exps` doesn't need to hold strings. Tuples would do just as well, if not better. The same goes for `pairs`.

```
from __future__ import division

from itertools import combinations

def strange_div(lhs, rhs):
    if -0.0001 < rhs < 0.0001:
        return 100000
    else:
        return lhs / rhs

def do_op(op, lhs, rhs):
    if op == '+':
        return lhs + rhs
    elif op == '*':
        return lhs * rhs
    elif op == '-':
        return lhs - rhs
    elif op == '^':
        return rhs - lhs
    elif op == '/':
        return strange_div(lhs, rhs)
    elif op == '%':
        return strange_div(rhs, lhs)
    raise ValueError("Unknown operator: {!r}".format(op))

def compute_step(operands, x_idx, y_idx, method, op):
    method.append((operands[x_idx], op, operands[y_idx]))
    new_operands = [num for x, num in enumerate(operands) if x != x_idx and x != y_idx]
    new_operands.append(do_op(op, operands[x_idx], operands[y_idx]))
    return new_operands

def find_close_calculations(operands, method):
    if len(operands) == 1:
        return 23.9999 < operands[0] < 24.0001

    pairs = set()
    for (i, lhs), (j, rhs) in combinations(enumerate(operands), 2):
        tmp_key = tuple(sorted((lhs, rhs)))
        if tmp_key in pairs:
            continue
        pairs.add(tmp_key)

        for op in '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '%':
            stepped = compute_step(operands, i, j, method, op)
            if find_close_calculations(stepped, method):
                print(str(method))
            method.pop()
```

Then we see `find_close_calculations` is doing

```
if find_close_calculations(stepped, method):
    print(str(method))
```

which is really a bit odd as it means `find_close_calculations([24], [])` won't print anything, it means we have a meaningless return value from calling it and it means we have to pass a strange second argument. Better would be to extract the recursive component out from the result-giving. Another fancier option is to generate `operands` differently.

```
def find_close_calculations(operands):
    if len(operands) == 1:
        if 23.9999 < operands[0] < 24.0001:
            yield []
        return

    pairs = set()
    for (i, lhs), (j, rhs) in combinations(enumerate(operands), 2):
        tmp_key = tuple(sorted((lhs, rhs)))
        if tmp_key in pairs:
            continue
        pairs.add(tmp_key)

        for op in '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '%':
            stepped = compute_step(operands, op, i, j)
            for method in find_close_calculations(stepped):
                method.append((lhs, op, rhs))
                yield method
```

This gives a generator of methods, rather than printing them, which is much more useful. Printing the output is thus done with

```
for method in find_close_calculations([3, 9, 10, 7]):
    print(method)
```

Since `new_operands` is an expensive copy anyway, you can simplify the chain by just passing a value and deleting more trivially:

```
def compute_step(operands, op, lhs, rhs):
    new_operands = operands.copy()
    new_operands.remove(lhs)
    new_operands.remove(rhs)
    new_operands.append(do_op(op, lhs, rhs))
    return new_operands

def find_close_calculations(operands):
    ...
    for lhs, rhs in combinations(operands, 2):
        ...
            stepped = compute_step(operands, op, lhs, rhs)
            ...
```

A little longer, but much more obvious of intent.